# Black screen output using Tensorflow's DeepLab

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, tensorflow2.0, deeplab

I trained DeepLab on my own dataset with both `initialize_last_layer` and `last_layers contain_logits` only both `False`. I have just 2 classes the background and the label. I tried using `--num_classes=2` and`3`but nothing worked. My `ignore_labe`l is `255` while my background is `(0,0,0,255)` and label is `(1,1,1,255)`. I also gave the `label_weights 1:20` but no use. All I see are black images in the `segmented_results` folder. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Define some colormap in your `vis.sh`

Eg.:

```
--colormap_type="cityscapes"
```